# ObjectMapper throws exception when JsonArray is passed to writeValueAsString

Tags: java, json, fasterxml

I am getting `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.json.JSONArray and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer`

Here is my code:

```
public class A{
@JsonProperty("ids")
private JSONArray ids;
@JsonProperty("count")
private String Count;
...
}

public class B {
....
@Autowired
    ObjectMapper mapper;

public String convert(Object obj){

   String response = mapper.writeValueAsString(obj);
   return response;
}
```

Is there a way to solve this issue? I cannot use `List<Class>` as underlying json structure is flexible.

Comment: Why are you using 2 different parsing libraries?

Comment: If your `ids` may contain any type, you'd better use plain raw-type `List` -  you may be requested to add `@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")` annotation to `private List ids;`